# Socket connection between React and Flask doesn't work

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, websocket, socket.io

I'm trying to set up a real-time connection between a React app and a Flask app with socket-io, i used the boilerplate code i found on the internet just to check if it works:

**in Flask** (socket.io verion 5.8.0):

```py
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
CORS(app, resources={r"/*": {"origins": "*"}})
socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins="*")


@app.route("/ok")
def main():
    print('APP')
    return 'APP'


@socketio.on("connect")
def connected():
    """event listener when client connects to the server"""
    print(request.sid)
    print("client has connected")
    emit("connect",{"data":f"id: {request.sid} is connected"})


@socketio.on('data')
def handle_message(data):
    """event listener when client types a message"""
    print("data from the front end: ",str(data))
    emit("data",{'data':data,'id':request.sid},broadcast=True)


@socketio.on("disconnect")
def disconnected():
    """event listener when client disconnects to the server"""
    print("user disconnected")
    emit("disconnect",f"user {request.sid} disconnected",broadcast=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, debug=True, port=8080)
```

**React Component** (socket.io version ^4.7.1):

```js
function PlayButton() {
  useEffect(() => {
    const socket = io('http://localhost:8080', {
    transports: ["websocket"],
    cors: {
      origin: "http://localhost:3000/",
      withCredentials: true,
    }}); // Replace with your Flask server URL

    socket.on('connect', () => {
      console.log('Connected to server');
    });

    socket.on('message', (data) => {
      console.log('Received message:', data);
    });

    socket.emit('message', 'Hello from client');

    return () => {
      socket.disconnect(); // Clean up the socket connection
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="play_button">
      Play
    </div>
  )
}
```

backend output:

```
 * Restarting with fsevents reloader
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: ***-***-***
```

when i run the react app i get the following errors/warnings:

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.

WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.
```